# NHibernate 1.x : many-to-one not lazily loaded

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading

This is extract of my mapping file:

```
<class name="XXX.A"
         table="a"
         lazy="false">

     <many-to-one name="B"
                  lazy="proxy"
                  access="field.camelcase"
                  cascade="none"
                  not-null="false"
                  class="XXX.B" 
                  column="id_b"/>

 </class>
```

But when `A` is loaded by its ID, I see "left join" to fetch `B`. How to prevent this?

I may add that we use `ISession.Get(...)` and not `ISession.Load(...)`.

Comment: Are your B's actual instances of B, or are they proxy objects (which they should according to your mapping)?

Comment: It's not a proxy. But there isn't only a left join on B, but left joins on B.X, B.Y... too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `<class name="XXX.B" lazy="false">` then NHibernate does not create a proxy class for it. Because of that all `<many-to-one class="XXX.B" lazy="proxy|true" />` are ignored because NH can not create proxy objects.

To enable LazyLoading of `B` remove `lazy="false"` or set `<class lazy="true">`. If you disabled Lazy for classes because you dont want to make every method virtual you can also implement your own Proxyclass to handle the LazyLoading